# Using datasets to predict the results for other devices

Tags: python, data-mining, predictive-modeling, feature-extraction

I have a datasets that contain results from a series of physical tests. It has about a dozen features and the outcome of each test is distinguished by 3 different classes.

The dataset includes features like: `[X, Y, Z, temperature, input voltage]`
 and as far as I know, these are all independent variables.

I then have a result column for the test `[failure, success, other]`

I have multiple of these datasets from testing of different devices.

I am trying to figure out if I can use the data from one device to predict the results for any of the other devices. If I can, I would like some way to measure how closely they are correlated, and which variables most strongly contribute to the prediction.

Comment: I'd like to add that I have investigated using decision trees trained on one dataset to predict the outcome of another, and have used the features that the tree is splitting on to get some insight.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Is there a term for what I am trying to do?